# Problem with algorithm2e: \SetAlgoLined and \Indp not working properly together

Tags: algorithm2e, parskip

### Problem:

I need to get something like this:

[image: Desired Output (generated with LaTeX + gimp)]

But I'm getting this (note the vertical line):

[image: What I get]

### What I have:

Here my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{SomeTitle}
    \label{alg:classes}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \footnotesize
        delRef(Refutation ref)\{\;
            \Indp
            Lanza Hilo que borra refutaciones en esta parte\;
            \If{se eliminaron refutaciones}{
                synczd $\leftarrow$ false\;
                actualizar size\;
            }
            \Indm
        \}\;
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

### Documentation:

I have checked [this documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) but I can't find how to draw those lines after the `\Indp`

As always, thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: i think that this is the same problem as asked about in your other question.  the documentation says that the margin of all algorithms depends on the sum of `'leftskip` and `\parindent` when the package is loaded.  so if you load `parskip` *after* loading `algorithm2e` it should take the original values for the `report` class.

Comment: makes sense, but unfortunately I get the same, even without parskip at all, check my edit

Comment: well, loading order fixed the other problem.  it looks to me like the line isn't observing the indentation request, and the documentation doesn't really help; lines are shown only in examples where they start in the leftmost possible "margin", and in your example, that's supposed to be empty.  needs someone with more experience, i'm afraid.

Comment: Exactly, they show only nice examples. Anyway, thank you so much for helping me with the other, if you get an idea of how to solve this, please let me know. :)

Comment: there was a new release late last year, so the author appears to be active.  send him an inquiry, asking in particular how to construct a "lined" algorithm where the first "key block" is indented, and suggest that such an example would be a helpful addition to the manual.

Comment: A couple of weeks ago I didn't know anything about latex, do I just send a mail to cfiorio@umontpellier.fr (the mail in the documentation)?

Comment: yes, the address in the documentation (if the update is reasonably recent) is always the best thing to use.

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer from the authors ?

Comment: I think I didn't receive answer, I tried to search across my email, but cannot find it (and cannot remember). Now I use the package [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is quite similar to [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544865/90297). The `\indp` and `\indm` are not good friends of `vlined`. What you could do if you wanted to indent is add a new (in this case empty) block using
`\SetKwBlock{DummyBlock}{}{}`
As in the previous answer, this would give the new dummy block a vertical line which can easily be removed with `\SetAlgoNoLine`. Then we set in the block `\SetAlgoLined' To have the vertical line on the If.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwBlock{DummyBlock}{}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{With Dummy}
    \label{alg:classes}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \footnotesize
        delRef(Refutation ref)\{
            \SetAlgoNoLine\DummyBlock{\SetAlgoLined
            Lanza Hilo que borra refutaciones en esta parte\;
            \If{se eliminaron refutaciones}{
                synczd $\leftarrow$ false\;
                actualizar size\;
            }}
        \}\;
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Notice here that the use of `\;` is important: it tells `algorithm2e` when to go down a new line. The Dummy block already feeds one line down so we can remove the `\;` at the end of line 1.

An even better solution would be to insert line 1 into a block:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwBlock{delRef}{delRef(Refutation ref)\{}{\}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{With new Block}
    \label{alg:classes}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \footnotesize
            \SetAlgoNoLine\delRef{\SetAlgoLined
            Lanza Hilo que borra refutaciones en esta parte\;
            \If{se eliminaron refutaciones}{
                synczd $\leftarrow$ false\;
                actualizar size\;
            }}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I was assuming this was not what you were looking for.

The results of both:
[image]