# parskip is shifting my algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e, parskip

### Problem:

I am using **parskip** (only) to add customized space between paragraphs, but the package is shifting my algorithm content to the left.

If there is another (clean) way to customize the space between paragraphs or isolate the algorithm environment, it is welcome:

### How does it looks:

[image]

And here the same code without parskip

[image]

### The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcommand{\bftab}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{SomeTitle}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \footnotesize
        delRef(Refutation ref)\{\;
            \Indp
            Some code lines\;
            Other one\;
            \Indm
        \}\;
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

As always, thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the documentation says that indents depend on the existing `\parindent`
and `\leftskip` when the package is loaded.

so try loading `parskip` after `algorithm2e`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the algorithm layout is assuming that `\parindent` is non zero. If you set it locally back to say 15pt, then the text is indented by that amount

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcommand{\bftab}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}\setlength\parindent{15pt}
    \caption{SomeTitle}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \footnotesize
        delRef(Refutation ref)\{\;
            \Indp
            Some code lines\;
            Other one\;
            \Indm
        \}\;
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, thank you. Just a little detail, the title still being shifted. Is there something for that?

Comment: @onlycparra -- as i noted in a comment to your [other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299679/579), the documentation says that indents depend on the existing `\parindent` and \leftskip` when the package is loaded.  so try loading `parskip` *after* `algorithm2e`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton reading the documentation is cheating:-)

Comment: [EDITED] as I commented him back (lol) the problem still happening even without parsnip at all. EDIT: sorry, I get confused with the other question, please forget this comment. I will try it

Comment: Done, loading parskip before solves the problem, please post an answer :)