# algorithm2e vertical line indentation

Tags: indentation, algorithm2e

I really like the vertical line feature of algorithm2e, but I ran into trouble with it when I try to indent an **if** statement. I used the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,fullpage,amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{\bf Generic Line Search Algorithm}

 {\bf Inputs:} Starting point $x_0$, initial step size parameter $\alpha_0$. \\
 \For{$k = 0,1,2,\dots$}{
    \nl {\bf Gradient approximation $g(x_k)$:}\\ \Indp
    Compute an approximation $g(x_k)$ of $\nabla \phi(x_k)$. \\ \Indm
    \nl {\bf Construct a search direction $d_k$:}\\ \Indp
    Construct a search direction $d_k$, e.g., $d_k = - g(x_k)$.\\ \Indm
    \nl {\bf Compute step size $\alpha_k$ and update the iterate:} \\ \Indp
    \eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_k d_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau^{-1} \alpha_k$
    }{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau \alpha_k$
    } 
 }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The texts were indented but the vertical lines in the **if** statement were not, as shown in the picture. 
[image: vertical line indentation issues in algorithm2e]
Does anyone know how to indent the vertical lines?

Comment: Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299679. It seems this is a known and not solved problem that `\vlined` and `\Indp` do not work properly together. I will try to investigate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- `\skiptext` (before vline space) and `\skiprule` (after vline space) are additionally updated inside indent adjusting command.
- No change to algorithm input.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,fullpage,amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Indentp}[1]{%
  \advance\leftskip by #1
  \advance\skiptext by -#1
  \advance\skiprule by #1}%
\renewcommand{\Indp}{\algocf@adjustskipindent\Indentp{\algoskipindent}}
\renewcommand{\Indpp}{\Indentp{0.5em}}%
\renewcommand{\Indm}{\algocf@adjustskipindent\Indentp{-\algoskipindent}}
\renewcommand{\Indmm}{\Indentp{-0.5em}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{\bfseries OP's example}

 \textbf{Inputs:} Starting point $x_0$, initial step size parameter $\alpha_0$. \\
 \For{$k = 0,1,2,\dots$}{
    \nl \textbf{Gradient approximation $g(x_k)$:}\\ \Indp
    Compute an approximation $g(x_k)$ of $\nabla \phi(x_k)$. \\ \Indm
    \nl \textbf{Construct a search direction $d_k$:}\\ \Indp
    Construct a search direction $d_k$, e.g., $d_k = - g(x_k)$.\\ \Indm
    \nl \textbf{Compute step size $\alpha_k$ and update the iterate:} \\ \Indp
    \eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_k d_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau^{-1} \alpha_k$
    }{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau \alpha_k$
    }
 }
\end{algorithm}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{More tests}
  \nl test \\
  \eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
    if clause
  }{
    else clause
  }
  \nl test \\ \Indp\Indp
  \eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
    if clause
  }{
    else clause
  } \Indm
  \nl test \\
  \eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
    if clause
  }{
    else clause
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Notes:

- `\Indp` (or `\Indm`) increases (or reduces) indentation by `\algoskipindent` (aka "step").
- This might not be the perfect solution, since I have not fully understand the `algorithm2e` internals `\algocf@Vline` and `\algocf@Vsline`.

Comment: Thank you. I am not an advanced user of Latex, but it seems like you just debugged the package. Could you elaborate what \skiptext, \skiprule, and \algoskipindent are, or if there is a good read on this?

Comment: @LiyuanCao Added some notes to my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments using vertical lines with `\indp` and `\indm` is a little buggy. The alternative is to turn the **Compute step size** into a block and thus allow the `algorithm2e` package to handle the indentation on its own in a better way.

This is done using `\SetKwBlock{Begin}{begin}{end}` macro:

```
\SetKwBlock{NewBlock}{Compute step size $\alpha_k$ and update the iterate:}{}
```

This would indent the if nicely, however, it would also add a vertical line for the new  **Compute step size** block. To remove that vertical line we add `\SetAlgoNoLine` and `\SetAlgoVlined`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,fullpage,amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,boxed]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwBlock{NewBlock}{Compute step size $\alpha_k$ and update the iterate:}{}
\caption{\bf Generic Line Search Algorithm}

\KwIn{Starting point $x_0$, initial step size parameter $\alpha_0$.}\;
\For{$k = 0,1,2,\dots$}{
   \nl {\bf Gradient approximation $g(x_k)$:}\; 
   \Indp Compute an approximation $g(x_k)$ of $\nabla \phi(x_k)$.\;

   \Indm \nl {\bf Construct a search direction $d_k$:}\; 
   \Indp Construct a search direction $d_k$, e.g., $d_k = - g(x_k)$.\; 


   \Indm\nl\SetAlgoNoLine\NewBlock{ \SetAlgoVlined\eIf{sufficient decrease condition is satisfied}{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_k d_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau^{-1} \alpha_k$\;
        }{
        $x_{k+1} = x_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} \gets \tau \alpha_k$\;
        }
    }
 }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

And the outcome:

[image]

Notice the following improvements from OP's MWE:

1. At the end of each line `\;` is used (no need for `\\`). In order not to print semicolons we use `DontPrintSemicolon`.
2. We use `algorithm2e` built-in `\KwIn` macro.

Comment: This is how I wanted to solve this problem originally, but I was not familiar with keyword blocks enough. One question: what is the benefit of using \; instead of \\?

Comment: The package documentation stresses that you must not forget to end each line with \;. It does so in a couple of places, and I think that has to do with the way the package identifies an end of line.